# M4 "No such file or directory".Bison

Tags: parsing, bison, yacc

This is my code in file skener.y

```
 %{
#include <stdio.h>
%}
%token T_Int
%%

exp:      T_Int           { $$ = $1;         }
| exp exp '+'     { $$ = $1 + $2;    }
| exp exp '-'     { $$ = $1 - $2;    }
| exp exp '*'     { $$ = $1 * $2;    }
| exp exp '/'     { $$ = $1 / $2;    }

;
%%
```

When I compile it with comand "bison -d skener.y" I get error "m4: No such file or directory.". Of course I am located in working folder when typing command in prompt. I dont know what is it about?

Answer (score 9):

There seems to be some error in the bison.exe file.
I replaced it with the one found inside this zip file.
http://marin.jb.free.fr/bison/bison-2.4.1-modified.zip

Source:http://marin.jb.free.fr/bison/

Answer (score 4):

There should be no space in the name of any folder in the path. In my case I kept it in C:/Program Files/GnuWin32/bin and it caused the error. Then I moved the folder from Program Files and placed as C:/GnuWin32/bin and it starts working well.

Answer (score 3):

I got this same error when I installed the [GnuWin32 version of bison](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/bison.htm) via their Setup.exe on my Windows 7 PC.  The solution was to add the `...\GnuWin32\bin` dir to my PATH.  (Interestingly, this is first tool of many that had a problem when not in my PATH)

Comment: This was part of the problem for me.  Tarun's solution was the other part.  I just modified the path within my batch file that calls BISON.  Thanks for this tip.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I solved it following the **jfritz42** answer, but had to add the

```
...\MinGW\bin
```

path too to my System Environment Variables...

Let screenshots of my case, hope it helps:)

[image: Step 1]

[image: Step 2]

[image: Step 3]

Answer (score 2):

Moved the Folder from

```
C:\Program Files(x86)\GnuWin32
```

to

```
C:\GnuWin32
```

then, added `PATH` values to both user variables and system variables as:

```
C:\GnuWin32\bin
```

Answer (score 0):

It means that you haven't installed bison properly -- you have an executable, but it is missing its support files.

Go back and reinstall bison.